# MIDI CC Button Settings on a Behringer BCR2000

Tags: midi

I have a Behringer BCR2000 which has customizable midi cc buttons along the top just like the BCF2000. I was wondering if I could press button 1 and set midi cc #90 (or whatever number) to 0, then press button 2 and set midi #90 to 25. Pressing button 3 would set #90 to 75 and so on. Is this possible? Thanks.

edit;

I've assigned two buttons to the same CC number (97, in this case.)
Set the `on` value for the first button to 0.
Set the `on` value for the second button to 25.
Set the `off` value for both buttons to "off" (disabled)

Now, when I link a knob to the CC number of the buttons, only the first one set does anything and it just decrements the current value of the knob by 10. Very strange.

Comment: I can't think of a reason why it wouldn't be possible.  The BCR2000 allows knobs to be assigned to the same value so I can't see why it'd be any different with buttons, but I can't try it myself at the moment.  Have you tried it?  Did you run into any problems?

Answer (score 1):

I uploaded the default settings via SysEx then did what I did in the edit again and it works.